# Does the following google script exactly delete the messages with certain label?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

My goal is to make sure that all incoming Gmail messages from test@test.com are immediately permanently deleted.

I have created a filter that gives new messages from this address the label "deleteforever". Next, I have made a Google script that completely deletes all messages with the label "deleteforever". To be certain that no other messages are deleted, I check an extra time whether the messages really are from test@test.com. In this way, when a thread contains messages from test@test.com and messages from another address, only the messages from test@test.com should be deleted.

I plan to run it every minute. I have 3 questions:

1. Does this algorithm always completely delete all new messages from test@test.com?
2. Does this algorithm never delete a message from another sender?
3. Will this not cost too much runtime, assuming that test@test.com does not send many emails? (I saw that there is a limit of 1 hour per day.)

```
function extractEmailAddress(header) {
  return header.match(/[^@<\s]+@[^@\s>]+/)[0];
}

function deleteForever() {
  var threads, msgs, label1, label2, sender,message,messageId;
  label1="test@test.com";
  label2="Test@test.com";

  threads= GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("deleteforever").getThreads();
  msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
      message=msgs[i][j];
      sender = extractEmailAddress(message.getFrom());
      if (sender==label1 || sender==label2){
         messageId=message.getId();
         Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", messageId);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Inspired by the comment of @TheMaster, the following strategy solves the potential runtime problem:

-modify the filter in Gmail so that messages from test@test.com skip the inbox.

-hide the "deleteforever" folder

Now the script can be run every 5 minutes or with even lower frequency.

Comment: Why not just mute the notifications for that label and delete later? Running a script each minute may add up to trigger total runtime of 90 minutes/day.

Comment: I hoped that using GmailApp.getUserLabelByName instead of GmailApp.search would be much faster, so that the total runtime is always very low

Comment: The idea of muting notifications is great! I will certainly apply that

Comment: You might also be interested in simply [blocking the sender](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151)

Comment: Simply blocking moves the message to spam, which is not the goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are open to muting the notifications as suggested by TheMaster and running the script/function on a less frequent basis, I suggest you improve it further by using `Gmail API`, specifically `batchDelete` to improve the performance.

#### Script:

```
function deleteForever() {
  label_name = 'deleteforever';
  sender1 = 'do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email';
  sender2 = 'forms-receipts-noreply@google.com';
  
  // get labelId of label_name
  var labelId = Gmail.Users.Labels.list("me").labels.filter(label => label.name == label_name)[0].id;
  // filter messages where it has labelId and from either sender1 or sender2
  var messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {
    "labelIds": labelId, 
    "q": `{from: ${sender1} from: ${sender2}}`
  }).messages;
  // if messages is not empty
  if(messages){
    // get ids of the messages
    var ids = messages.map(message => message.id);
    // bulk delete the messages
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({"ids": ids}, "me");
  }
}
```

This will delete the accumulated message IDs by bulk where it meets the conditions:

- Sender is either `sender1` or `sender2`
- Has label `label_name`.

#### Note:

- You will not need `extractEmailAddress` anymore.